# Why does my site not being auto responsive after using bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsiveness

I'm not missing meta tag..
I wanna know is there any relation between markup & responsiveness? I mean if my markup is not good then less chance to getting responsive?

There are 4break point in bootstrap but i keep doing media query but can't make my site perfect responsive :( it's annoying writing too much media query..

It's easy to code for big screen but when try to make it responsive for small devices i get problems.

I'm making this website myself using bootstrap can you check and tell me what is wrong in my codes markup?
http://uksmail.com
Thank you

Comment: This question is very hard to answer. Perhaps you can edit it and include the relevant parts of your code, along with a more specific description of expected vs. observed behavior? See [ask]

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/

Comment: sir i've edited my post :)

Comment: The website looks responsive to me https://imgur.com/a/p8OIj . Please specify your issue exactly and as the above comment said add relevant code.